# Datetime conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
declare @v1 datetime = getdate();
declare @v2 int = 2;
select @v1 + @v2;
---------------------------
2013-01-06 08:16:20.620
```

But

```
declare @v1 datetime = getdate();
declare @v2 char(1) = '2';
select @v1 + @v2;
--------------------------
```

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

gives error. But both `int @v2` and `char @v2` have the same value?

Comment: `int @v2` and `char @v2` don't have the same value. one has an int and one has a char

Comment: ethorm10: my question is why chat doesnt get converted while on the other hand int gets.if you change val2 char(2)='2' to val2 char(10)='20130104' than it gives no error.

Comment: Why are you randomly adding together values of different types? What result are you expecting? If you really want to add `2` to a `datetime` value, you've already found a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

When combining two operators of different types you will have an implicit type conversion. What gets converted is controlled by the [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190309.aspx) rules.

Both `char` and `int` has lower precedence than datetime so your query is the equivalent of:

```
select @v1 + cast(@v2 as datetime);
```

Casting int value `2` to a `datetime` works just fine and gives you `1900-01-03 00:00:00.000`

Casting a char value `2` to a datetime does however not work since the string `2` can not be interpreted as a valid datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

when char was converted to  datetime.. it is usually false..because some chars can't be converted to datetime..and can  overflow..just like '2','a' etc..

you need a char value  which like '2013-01-04'...they can be converted correctly..